# Switching activities with if statements and a random number generator

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-intent

I'm using a random number generator and IF Statements to switch between activities. It iterates through the first if statement and stops there. I don't think my random number generator is generating any random numbers. Thanks in advance.

```
package app.com.example.android.oraclethedeciscionmaker;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import java.util.Random;

public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
    }

    public void onClick(View view){

        Random guess = new Random();

        int guesser0 = guess.nextInt(0) + 1;
        int guesser1 = guess.nextInt(0) + 1;
        int guesser2 = guess.nextInt(0) + 1;
        int guesser3 = guess.nextInt(0) + 1;
        int guesser4 = guess.nextInt(0) + 1;

        int result = guesser0 + guesser1 + guesser2 + guesser3 + guesser4;

        // 0 out of 0
        if(result == 0){
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, ZeroOfFive.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            // If this statement is true go to this activity
        }
        // 1 out of 5
        else if(result == 1){
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, OneOfFive.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            // If this statement is true go to this activity
        }
        //2 out of 5
        else if(result == 2){
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, TwoOfFive.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            // If this statement is true go to this activity
        }
        //3 out of 5
        else if(result == 3){
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, ThreeOfFive.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            // If this statement is true go to this activity
        }
        //4 out of 5
        else if(result == 4){
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, FourOfFive.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            // If this statement is true go to this activity

        }
        //5 out of 5
        else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, FiveOfFive.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it means result is 0.

Comment: Why do you think it does not work?

Comment: guess.nextInt(x) returns a random number from 0 to x. in your case, it is 0 to 0. So it is always 0 which is kind of constant 0 for you. Use something like guess.nextInt(100) , so that it generates random number between 0 to 100 everytime. Or use some big number as your need.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `guess.nextInt(0)` that generates a random number between 0 and what you passed in, which was 0 (exclusive). To get a random number between 1 and 5, you should use something like `guess.nextInt(5) + 1`. I think in this case result would always be 5, but I'd use a debugger or print out the value [Logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html) to check.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple modification !

```
package app.com.example.android.oraclethedeciscionmaker;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import java.util.Random;

public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
    }

    public void onClick(View view){

        Random guess = new Random();

        int result= guess.nextInt(6); // this result can be varies from 0 to 5 

        // 0 out of 5
        if(result == 0){
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, ZeroOfFive.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            // If this statement is true go to this activity
        }
        // 1 out of 5
        else if(result == 1){
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, OneOfFive.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            // If this statement is true go to this activity
        }
        //2 out of 5
        else if(result == 2){
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, TwoOfFive.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            // If this statement is true go to this activity
        }
        //3 out of 5
        else if(result == 3){
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, ThreeOfFive.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            // If this statement is true go to this activity
        }
        //4 out of 5
        else if(result == 4){
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, FourOfFive.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            // If this statement is true go to this activity

        }
        //5 out of 5
        else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, FiveOfFive.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```